# поиск номера телефона в тексте

Tags: java

Добый день! Помогите пожалуйста с задачей. Нужно написать ыункцию, которая принимает номер телефона и выдает есть ли он в тексте. Номер тлф может быть введен по разному. Функцию написал и регулярное выражение вроде бы правильное. Но результат постоянно один и тот же "the number is NOT exist"

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PhoneNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter phone");
        String phone = in.nextLine();
        isPhone(phone);
    }


    public static boolean isPhone(String phone) throws IOException {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\s*)?(\\+)?([- _():=+]?\\d[- _():=+]?){10,14}(\\s*)?$");
        Matcher editPhone = p.matcher(phone);

        String contents = getTextFromFile("/home/qa-1/HW");
        String[] severalWords = breakIntoWords(contents);
        for (int i = 0; i < severalWords.length; i++) {
            if (editPhone.equals(severalWords[i])) {
                System.out.println("the number is exist");
                return true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("the number is NOT exist");
        return false;
    }

    public static String getTextFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
    }

    public static String[] breakIntoWords(String text) {
        text = text.replaceAll("[,;:.!?\\s-]+", " ");
        return text.split("\\s+");
    }
}
```

Comment: не совсем точная постановка вопроса... что значит "по разному"? номер телефона, как не крути - это цифры. кто мешает выполнять поиск только по цифрам?

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович "8 января 2017 года 22 студента купили вскладчину 34 чебурека и 12 бутылок пива"

Comment: я пользуюсь таким регекспом `"[7|8][ (-]?[\\d]{3}[ )-]?[\\d]{3}[ -]?[\\d]{2}[ -]?[\\d]{2}[\\D]"` для российских мобильных номеров

Answer (score 0):

Для начала надо определиться, какие символы может содержать телефон. Для разных стран и городов количество цифр может отличаться.

Допустим нас интересуют мобильные телефоны РФ.

Правила такие:

- телефон начинается с `8` либо `+7`
- цифры могут разделяться пробелом и символом `-`
- код оператора может быть заключен в скобки

Соответственно первым шагом удаляем из текста эти символы, а вторым выбираем все последовательности из 11 чисел, начинающиеся с 7 или 8:

```
String text = ".......";
String prepared = ","+text.replaceAll("[ -()]", "")+",";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^\\d]([78]\\d{10})[^\\d]")
    .matcher(prepared);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Данный код, естественно, может давать ложные срабатывания, либо не срабатывать когда надо на сложных случаях, но идея должна быть понятна

Answer (score -1):

берете эту библиотеку 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.7
она расширит функционал работы со строками

и делаете так, а потом думаете, что еще можно оптимизировать

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String contents = getDigitFromFile("/home/qa-1/HW");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter phone");
        System.out.println(isPhone(in.nextLine(), contents));
    }

    public static String isPhone(String phone, String contents) {
        if (contents.contains(StringUtils.getDigits(phone))) 
            return "the number is exist";
        else return "the number is NOT exis";
    }

    public static String getDigitFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return StringUtils.getDigits(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName))));
    }
```

}